# How to invert a hash, maintaining duplicate keys

Tags: ruby

From an initial hash `t`:

```
t = {"1"=>1, "2"=>2, "3"=>2, "6"=>3, "5"=>4, "4"=>1, "8"=>2, "9"=>2, "0"=>1, "7"=>1}
```

I need to swap the keys and values as follows:

```
t = {"1"=>1, "2"=>2, "3"=>2, "6"=>3, "5"=>4, "1"=>4, "8"=>2, "9"=>2, "1"=>0, "1"=>7}
```

While maintaining the structure of the hash (ie, without collapsing duplicate keys).

Then I'll make an array out of this hash.

Is there a way to do this? I tried this:

```
t.find_all{ |key,value| value == 1 }   # pluck all elements with values of 1
#=> [["1", 1], ["4", 1], ["0", 1], ["7", 1]]
```

But it returns a new array, and the initial hash isn't changed.

The following doesn't work either:

```
t.invert.find_all{ |key,value| value == 1 }  
#=> []
```

Comment: invalid hash, your expected one.

Comment: You cannot have a single value be the key to multiple elements in a hash.

Comment: What do you expect t["1"] to return ?

Comment: Need to hash elements having value == 1 swapped with their key

Comment: without affecting other elements of the hash.It is a challenge to build a sequence of numbers: 
1 
11 
21 
1211 
111221 
312211

Comment: @user3453560 I'm not sure a hash is the best way to do this. Can you provide more details about your challenge?

Comment: As said earlier, what you need is impossible, due to the fact a hash table is indexed by its keys, it is a one-to-one mapping, one key points to one value. Two identical keys **cannot** be physically present in a hash table. Be aware that the textual representation of a hash table as you posted it is in **no way** identical to how it really exists in memory.

Comment: @SirDarius (and to whomever upvoted SirDarius's comment) No, you are absolutely wrong. Hash is a map, but is not a one-to-one map. Many keys can point to a single value. You are as wrong as the OP.

Comment: @sawa the point is moot, but you are misinterpreting my comment. I didn't mean that values must be unique, I merely (tried to) say that a hash map **entry** is *one* key that points to *one* value. Hope this clears things up ;)

Comment: @SirDarius You are repeating the same mistake.

Comment: @sawa Then, for the sake of learning things, please tell me what is wrong with the sentance "a hash map entry is one key that points to one value" (ignoring fundamental storage issues, like collision resolution and other advanced stuff, I'm talking about the user point-of-view).

Comment: @SirDarius It is redundant. There is no map that takes one key and points to more than one value. That is a relation, not a map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do this:

```
>> t = {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 2, "6" => 3, "5" => 4, "4" => 1, "8" => 2, "9" => 2, "0" => 1, "7" => 1}
```

`Hash#compare_by_identity` allows for keys that are duplicates by value but unique by object id:

```
>> h = Hash.new.compare_by_identity
>> t.each_pair{ |k,v| h[v.to_s] = v.to_i }
```

The inverse hash of `t`:

```
>> h
#=> {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "2" => 3, "3" => 6, "4" => 5, "1" => 4, "2" => 8, "2" => 9, "1" => 0, "1" => 7}
```

You can then use `find_all` to retrieve an array of elements without mutating `h`:

```
>> h.find_all{ |k,_|  k == "1" }
#=> [["1", 1], ["1", 1], ["1", 1], ["1", 1]]
```

or `keep_if` to return the mutated `h`:

```
>> h.keep_if{ |k,_|  k == "1"  }        
#=> {"1"=>1, "1"=>1, "1"=>1, "1"=>1}
>> h
#=> {"1"=>1, "1"=>1, "1"=>1, "1"=>1}
```

Note that this solution assumes you want to maintain the pattern of string keys and integer values in your hash. If you require integer keys, `compare_by_identity` won't be helpful to you.

Comment: You cannot switch the keys and the values even if you use `compare_by_identity` because the supposed keys are immediate values. You silently/secretly converted the supposed keys into strings and the supposed values into numerals.

Comment: Thanks for a help also came up with a solution